# Different image in custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a custom cell with 3 buttons and text. Above have a segmented control to change my list (diary | Fav) (just update the tableview in the same controller)

In first tableview when I push the "fav button" I save this value on my other tableview (is to save my favourite contacts) and change the imagen button. This work, but when i back from fav list, only see with the new photo my last contact saved. I use this on my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**

```
if posicionSegmented() == 1 {
    cell.botonFav.setImage(UIImage(named: imagenFav[1])!, forState: .Normal)
   }else{ 
     for (index, element) in rescataNombresFav().enumerate() {
      if(element as! String == cell.getNombreCelda()){
        cell.botonFav.setImage(UIImage(named: imagenFav[1])!, forState: .Normal)
         //return cell
        }else {
          cell.botonFav.setImage(UIImage(named: imagenFav[0])!, forState: .Normal)
                    //return cell
              }
       }
```

**EDIT**

I press my star button to add favourite:

[image]

Then in favourite i have my favs with the star button like i want

[image]

The problem is when i back, only the last added to fav cell is black

[image]

Comment: Will you explain your problem in detail?

Comment: @Jigar Tarsariya added images ^^

Comment: What you had written for segment 0 ?

Comment: i have the same, just want to change the image

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I have to return in the if and return at the end of the method, but not in the else.